# How to save data in disk cache properly?

Tags: python, packaging

I want to save data between runs of my `python` application (data should be the same for different users). The best way I have found was save it in file on disk. Directory `/var/cache/my_package` looks good for this purposes, but I faced a few difficulty:

1. how to create this folder during the installation
2. how to set owner and access rules
3. how to access cache files without hardcoding absolute path

I have found [data_file](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#data-files) option in `setuptools` but it can't help with points 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`diskcache` does exactly what you are looking for!

Check out examples here: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/tutorial.html

Comment: can someone approve an edit of this, so it no longer condescending, and actually provides information? The edit queue is full but right now it's jut a link